# How to configure NodeMCU bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, esp32, nodemcu

I need to configure the Bluetooth of NodeMCU. I will be sending a lot of devices to my clients, and they will configure the device settings using an Android application over Bluetooth. I want to assign a serial number to each device and set their Bluetooth names to match their respective serial numbers. If possible, I might even set passwords for them. I tried searching on Google, but I could only find guides for configuring HC modules. However, I intend to use NodeMCU's built-in Bluetooth.  I also did a bit of searching here, but unfortunately, I couldn't find anything useful. I don't know, maybe I might have missed something. Is there anyone who can assist me in configuring NodeMCU's built-in Bluetooth, or could you provide a link to redirect me to a helpful resource?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written any code for Android? What do you know about Bluetooth programming? Are you familiar with its terms like central or peripheral roles?

Comment: the NodeMCU board (esp8266) doesn't have Bluetooth

Comment: @Kozmotronik nothing specific for this project yet. I am currently in the planning phase, considering what I can do. However, in the past, I have experience in developing classic or low energy Bluetooth communication systems for Android. Additionally, I have used various Arduino, ESP, and STM boards to establish Bluetooth communication. At times, I utilized built-in Bluetooth, while in other cases, I employed Bluetooth modules like HC-05 or HM-10.

Comment: @Juraj the NodeMCU board has built-in Bluetooth. I have used it for BLE communication. Moreover, upon reviewing the technical details, it seems that it also supports classic Bluetooth. I am uncertain whether it uses ESP8266 or a different chipset, but I am positive that it has Bluetooth capabilities.

Comment: That's great! Then you should have enough experience with all those practices to get things done. I haven't practiced with NodeMCU yet, however when I look at the docs, I would agree with @Juraj. Because in the [docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/) it is stated that NodeMCU is for programmin ESP8266 chips and I know that those chips don't have a builtin Bluetooth while ESP32 chips do. So, if you've done with programming Android's Bluetooth, first of all you need to develop configuration functions in for your NodeMCU in Lua language.

Comment: @Kozmotronik NodeMCU is a name used for the Lua fw and for the development board designed by NodeMcu fw creators. I guess OP uses the board with Arduino not with Lua. there are Esp32 NodeMcu boards, but OP tagged the question with [esp8266]

Comment: @Juraj you are right. I was wrong to tag as [esp8266]

Comment: Thanks to both of you @Kozmotronik. I found some examples. I will show codes when I complete my project. So anyone else can see and learn